# html date format yyyy mm dd hh24 mi ss AS INPUT TYPE IN HTML

Tags: html, datetime, attributes, input-type-range

TODAY I tried IN HTML TAG `INPUT` with `DATETIME` attribute but It's not warking AS shown below

```
Start Time: <br><input type="datetime" name="TOI" ><br>
```

But There is only A input Type Box Not calender AS I papoose there.. 
I have to submite a value="`2015-04-01 12:52:19`"..
Need both Time and date but in `input type` it's not working...
Can anyone tell me why it's not working..

Comment: But It's working with Datetime-local.. And I need only datetime as a Type..

Comment: Is there any other solution For PHP ..I am working on as on php also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` elements with `type="datetime"` are not supported in Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox or Opera 15 and newer. Partial support in Safari. Full support in Opera 12 and earlier versions.

Access an Input Datetime Object
You can access an `<input>` element with `type="datetime"` by using `getElementById():`

`var x = document.getElementById("myDatetime");` Try it
Tip: You can also access `<input type="datetime">` by searching through the elements collection of a form.

Create an Input Datetime Object
You can create an `<input>` element with `type="datetime"` by using the `document.createElement()` method:

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "datetime");
```

OR you can use `<input type="datetime-local" name="date">`

You can also use many built libraries available like bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks For JS CODE.. :)

Comment: Pleasure that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is just not supported at the moment, unfortunately, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_datetime.asp
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

**HTML**

```
Start Time: <br><input type="datetime-local" name="TOI"><br>
```

Take a look at this [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_datetime-local).
And all [input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Comment: That's how your computer is configurated. I don't have AM and PM because i'm using a 24 hour clock.